# Ansible replace code in multiple files in a directory

Tags: linux, centos, ansible

I'm trying to disable all repos on my server using ansible, so I'm trying to do a replace on multiple files within one directory but can't seem to get it to work any idea appreciated!

```
tasks:

  - name: get repo names
    raw: find /etc/yum.repos.d/ -type f -name "*.repo"
    register: repos

  - name: disable all repos
    replace: dest={{repos}} regexp="enabled=1" replace="enabled=0"
    with_items: repos.stdout_lines
```

When I run this I just get an error like it's trying to do them all at once? How would I split them up if that was the case?

> /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Debuginfo.repo\r\n/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo\r\n/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo\r\n'} does not exist !",

update:

```
  - find:
      paths: "/etc/yum.repos.d/"
      patterns: "*.repo"
    register: repos

  - name: disable all repos
    replace: dest={{items}} regexp="enabled=1" replace="enabled=0"
    with_items: repos
```

The new error is following:
"msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'items' is undefined

Okay Getting closer! getting this error at the disable repo now:

```
FAILED! => {
    "failed": true,
    "msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout_lines'"
}
```

Answer (score 10):

This question seems to have trailed off without fully completing... at least not with using `find`. Here is an example of the 2-step process that was sought after. The case for using `raw` for the first case has been answered. But I find this solution more appealing, even if harder:

```
tasks:
- name: Find all of the files inside this directory
  find:
    paths: "/etc/yum.repos.d/"
    patterns: "*.repo"
  register: repos

- name: Replace foo with bar in the files
  replace:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    regexp: 'foo'
    replace: 'bar'
  with_items: "{{ repos.files }}"
```

This required some research on the output structure of the `find` command.

Comment: This worked for me. The Ansible docs say you should use `ansible.builtin.replace` instead of `replace` in your YAML.

Answer (score 4):

It is "trying them all at once", because you are providing the whole output of the previous task as an argument for the `dest`:

```
dest={{repos}}
```

Instead, you should be feeding the items you iterate over:

```
dest={{item}}
```

---

You also don't quote the variable in the `with_items`.

Second task should look like this:

```
- name: disable all repos
  replace: dest={{item}} regexp="enabled=1" replace="enabled=0"
  with_items: "{{ repos.stdout_lines }}"
```

---

Besides, you can use [`find` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/find_module.html) instead of `raw` command.

Comment: Hi Updated above sorry didnt realise it wouldn't show okay on a comment!

Comment: Thanks for that, I don't think the find is correctly storing the information for the disable read from possibly? added new error, thanks again!

Comment: Trying something similar

`- name: Find files with yaml
  find:
    path: "$HOME/kube_objs/"
    pattern: "*.yaml"
  register: kubespecs

- name: Replace docker repository
  replace: dest={{ item }} regexp="11.168.25.68" replace='x'
  with_items: "{{ kubespecs.stdout_lines }}"
`
But getting the same error as mentuioned above
 "'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout_lines'"}

Tried with {{ kubespecs }} instead of {{item}} as well

Please help.

Comment: You explain she should use {{item}}, then you go on and use {{repos}} anyway. That's not really helpful.

Comment: @bviktor Thank you for spotting the typo and kindly letting me know.

Comment: Thanks, upped the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The error was: 'items' is undefined

this is because u must use "item" instead of items in

```
 dest=

(dest={{item}})
```

, but with `items`

so the proper way is:

```
- name: disable all repos
  replace: dest={{item}} regexp="enabled=1" replace="enabled=0"
  with_items: repos
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to fullfill the answer from AlanSE:

```
tasks:
- name: Find all of the files inside this directory
  find:
    paths: "/etc/yum.repos.d/"
    patterns: "*.repo"
  register: repos

- name: Replace foo with bar in the files
  replace:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    regexp: 'foo'
    replace: 'bar'
  loop: "{{ repos.results | json_query('[*].files') | flatten }}"
```

This should work perfectly fine.